# how can I set an array in cookie? - laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

in laravel, how can I set an array in cookie ?

for example :

```
$test = array(
'fname'=>'test',
'lname'=>'test'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Cookie::queue('array_name['.$id.']',1, 9999)`

Answer (score -1):

```
$test = array(
   'fname'=>'test',
   'lname'=>'test'
);
$response->withCookie(cookie('name', $test, 60));

return $response;
```

From Laravel documentation.